# Formal proof of existence of equivalent parse tree for each derivation

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Where I can find formal proof of there exists an equivalent parse tree for each derivation? There is a lot of informal proof of equivalency on the internet but I need formal proof to reference it in a paper.

Comment: There is no need to reference such a trivial fact in a paper.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus can you please direct me to formal proof?

Comment: You can take look at any decent textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposition 6.11

*Full manuscript*: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/gbooks/tocnotes.html](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ejean/gbooks/tocnotes.html)

> Definition 3.11.2: Given a context-free grammar $G = (V, \Sigma, P,
> > S)$, for any $A \in N$, if $\pi: A \stackrel{n}{\implies} \alpha$ is a
> derivation in $G$, we construct an *A-derivation tree* $t_\pi$ with
> yield $\alpha$ as follows.
>
> 1. if $n = 0$, then $t_\pi$ is the one-node tree such that $dom(t_{\pi}) = \{ \epsilon \}$ and $t_{\pi}(\epsilon) = A$
> 2. if $A \stackrel{n-1}{\implies} \lambda B \rho$ and if $t_1$ is the A-derivation tree with yield $\lambda B \rho$ associated with the
>    derivation $A \stackrel{n-1}{\implies} \lambda B \rho$, and if $t_2$
>    is the tree associated with the production $B \rightarrow \gamma$
>    that is, if $\gamma = X_1 \dots X_n$,
>
> then $dom(t_2) = \{ \epsilon, 1, \dots, k \}$, $t_2(\epsilon) = B$,
> and $t_2(i) = X_i$ or all $i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$, of if $\gamma = \epsilon$
>
> then $dom(t_2) = \{ \epsilon, 1 \}$, $t_2(\epsilon) = B$, and $t_2(1) = \epsilon$,
>
> then $t_{\pi} = t_1[u \gets t_2]$, where $u$ is the address of the
> leaf labeled $B$ in $t_1$.
>
> The tree $t_{\pi}$ is the *A-derivation tree associated* with the
> derivation $A \stackrel{n-1}{\implies} \alpha$.

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: ["Hyperlink-only" posts are frowned upon](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), for one thing, links may become stale. When possible to do so without IP violation, [quote](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) the essential part.